# To long request from client to server asp.net mvc+ef+IIS Express

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

About project:
I use asp.net mvc 4, Entity framework 6, SQL Server 2014, IIS Express 7.5. And the problem is when i try to call some page or refresh it, it takes a very long time(about 30-40 sec) to load this page. Maybe it will help: when i paste a break-point in controller action in takes about 25 sec after I refresh page before this break-point will be reached. Any ideas?

Comment: This can be anything, connection, database design, IIS configuration, code... You have to be more specific.

Comment: @GertArnold, you`re right but i can`t give more information because, it works fine yesterday...I only make commit to repository and when today I run project I face such problem. I know, it sounds like there is some magic  here, but its all that I have now

Comment: IIS Express is simply not IIS. Removed IIS tag.

Comment: Then you need to look in that commit. Maybe share what you did?